# Java Media Framework: how do I install JMF for mac?

Tags: java, macos, jmf

On the sun Website, there have download options for windows, solaris, and linux.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this page - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/setup-138642.html

> JMF 2.1.1 -- A cross-platform version
>   of JMF for Java clients. To set up on
>   a Java client, you need to download
>   the Cross-platform Java install
>   package, which contains only Java
>   bytecodes (no native code). Note the
>   Java Sound API reference
>   implementation is not included with
>   the cross-platform version of JMF.

Select any platform and proceed to their page.... there you will get a link for a Cross-platform Java version  `jmf-2_1_1e-alljava.zip`

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-source framework called fmj. It supports linux, windows and mac. I gathered good experiences with this framework.

http://fmj-sf.net/index.php

Comment: Is that copyleft? It has the LGPL license, and I'm not sure about LGPL... they make those things so wordy

Comment: Yes, it is. The difference between GPL and LGPL is that you can use your own license for your software using LGPL-libs. If you use GPL-software you have to use also the GPL for your software.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License